# Segmentation fault when displaying environment variables in shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, ubuntu, environment-variables

I am coding a shell in Ubuntu and I am using the following function to output the environment variables to the user.

```
    extern char **environ;


    void showEnv()
    {
         while (*environ != NULL)
              printf("%s\n",*environ++);
    }
```

However, when this function is called, the environment variables all displayed correctly, but the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" is displayed and the process terminates.

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your `environ` string may not be NULL terminated. This will never trigger the stop condition of the while loop and will cause the sigsegv error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you do `environ++`, you alter the `environ` pointer.**  After your loop finishes, any library code that tries to access `environ` will find that it points to a NULL pointer, as though the environment is empty.  It's probably not expecting that, and it's surely not what you want.

Use a temporary pointer variable to step through the array instead:

```
char **p = environ;
while (*p != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", *p++);
}
```

Just for completeness, I'll point out that the `environ` array is [guaranteed by the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) to always be NULL-terminated, so your while loop's stop condition will be triggered. You don't have to worry about that.